# MongoDB how to query that nested array sub-document doesn't contain a key value

Tags: mongodb

Say I have

```
user1 = user{
  id: some_id2
  books: [
    {
      category: sience,
      title: book1
    },
    {
      category: art,
      title: book2
    },
    {
      category: science,
      title: book3
    }
  ]
}

user2 = user{
  id: some_id
  books: [
    {
      category: sience,
      title: book1
    },
    {
      category: science,
      title: book3
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I'd like to fire a query so that I only get back user2. something like `{'books.category': {$ne: 'art'}}`, but this query is clearly wrong as I get both users back. What is the correct query for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong there, i have tested your case and the query you mentioned returns only user 2 as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query you can use `$elemMatch`. The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

```
{"books": {$elemMatch: { "category" : {$ne: "art"}}}}
```

Comment: Hey 夢のの夢, I don't have the actual collections with me, Can you please verify that this answer solves your problem ?